# How do I make GridPane fill the entire scene? (JavaFX SceneBuilder w/ Eclipse Luna)

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

[I found this answer but it seems to be outdated or not applicable to my situation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919241/gridpane-to-horizontally-vertically-fill-the-whole-stage)

I (along with the remainder of my class) am trying to resize my GridPane to fill the entire scene.  Here is what it looks like in SceneBuilder now:

[image: GridPane doesn't fill full scene?]

If you cannot see the image:  It's simply an image of a 3x3 GridPane (the only element in my Hierachy) with the "gray space" of the remaining scene surrounding the GridPane.

This is my main code:

```
    package pkgTicTacToe;

    import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane root = (GridPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ticTacToe.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
package pkgTicTacToe;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class ticTacToeController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private GridPane root;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        Image imageX = new Image(getClass().getResource("/pkgTicTacToe/x.gif").toExternalForm());
        Image imageO = new Image(getClass().getResource("/pkgTicTacToe/o.gif").toExternalForm());
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                int status = (int)(Math.random() * 3 );
                if (status == 0) {
                root.add(new ImageView(imageX), j, i);
                }
            else if (status == 1) {
                root.add(new ImageView(imageO), j, i);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

This is the code in my .fxml file  (in our class we do not "mess" with the .fxml directly, we manipulate these elements via SceneBuilder, and mostly code in the controller):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<GridPane fx:id="root" alignment="CENTER" gridLinesVisible="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="301.0" prefWidth="465.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="pkgTicTacToe.ticTacToeController">
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" />
   </rowConstraints>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

I have tried manipulating all the different elements of Properties, Layout, and Code on the right hand side, and have looked through the menu options at the top -- there doesn't seem to be a way to make this sucker fit!  I have thought of creating an AnchorPane to place the GridPane inside of, but that circumvents my problem rather than really finding a solution.

I would prefer an answer that is oriented towards using SceneBuilder for the sake of the remainder of my class.  However, if you also include a code method, I would enjoy that as well, as I personally prefer to work less with GUI and more directly with the keyboard.

Thanks for your time, I apologize if I have left any details out or did not do enough research on my own to find a similar question.

Comment: may i ask why you think the other solution is outdated? - try wrapping the `gridpane` into an `anchorpane` and it should work fine.

Comment: I wanted a solution that didn't require wrapping in another pane. :(

Answer (score 3):

The root element of a scene will always fill the entire scene, so when you run your application your grid pane is filling the scene. (Just try putting a background color on it.) However, the grid pane itself contains empty space. (What you see in SceneBuilder is of course pretty arbitrary, as SceneBuilder only knows about the FXML, and the scene itself is defined and sized externally to that.)

What you're probably really asking is how to make the content of the grid pane fill the grid pane (i.e. you want the columns to take up all of the width of the grid pane between them). Notice that you have set all three columns to have a preferred width of 100; since your scene has width 400, this leaves 100 pixels of unused space. (Similarly with the rows.)

Remove the `prefWidth` setting on the column constraints, and set all column constraints to have a `hgrow` value of `ALWAYS`. (Similarly for the rows, `prefHeight` and `vgrow`.)

Comment: This didn't work for me, I got very weird behavior after I did what you suggested. Now girdPane is filled but the cells of the grid pane are all over the scene, they are not arranged the way they should be. When I eliminate vGrow and vHeight priority constraints cells of gridPane are normal again, but they are no longer filling the scene.

Comment: @catloverxx There’s not enough detail in a comment to diagnose what’s wrong. Create and post your own question, with a complete [mre].